# Crashing on startActivity when clicking button

Tags: java, android, android-button

Having the same issue. The button is initialized at the right time but for some reason, it crashes on click. The xml file says the onClick handler is missing the related activity.

*xml*

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_reg_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="216dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="@string/need_a_new_account" />
```

*Java*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    mRegBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_reg_btn);

    mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent reg_intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(reg_intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Very new to android programming. Any help is appreciated

Comment: make sure the R.layout.activity.start  xml has this button.

Comment: It does the xml code I posted is from the acitvity_start.xml file

Comment: may be because of android:onClick="onClick" and you have not created this method in your activity, so try after remove this line.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of solving your issue:

1. When you declare onClick handler in your XML, you need to implement the method in your activity.

In your case, you have declared an onClick handler for your button on XML with this line:

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

So, you now have to create a method name onClick() in your activity and do your code there like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent reg_intent = new Intent( StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
  startActivity(reg_intent);
}
```

2. Remove this line from your XML:

```
 android:onClick="onClick"
```

and do what you did already:

```
mRegBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent reg_intent = new Intent( StartActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(reg_intent);
            }
        });
```

So, the main concept is this you can't use `android:onClick` and `setOnClickListener` together. You have to use one at a time.

Comment: I removed the android:onClick="onClick" attribute from the button on the xml file but it still crashes on click

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> android:onClick and `setOnClickListener` can not used simultaneous.
> ```

To use android:onClick correctly, you could refer to [the official link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting current context using `getContext()` and implement as.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent reg_intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(reg_intent);
}
```

And either define `onClick` from xml file or define it programmatically using `View.setOnClickListener`. Both can not co-exist.

Comment: removed the android:onClick="onClick" so that they don't co-exist but it still crashes on click. I rebuild before running and it still crashes on click of that button

Answer (score 0):

Found the error that the TextEditinput != TextInputLayout and that's why it was crashing. It was also working either by the onClick Method or SetuponClickListener so thank you for everyone and their help